# Only displaying fields with a record in Web2py

Tags: python, web2py

I have the following fields in `db.define_table('mydatabase',` `Field('a_1'),`...to `Field('a_9')` then `Field('b_1'),`...to `Field('b_9')` and `Field('c_1','upload'),`...to `Field('c_9','upload')`

This adds up to a total of 27 `Fields`

Not all 9 `Fields` of `a`, `b`, and `c` will always have a record. However, if `Field('a_1')` has a record, then all the other Fields will have a record also.

In the View, I only want to display the `Fields` with a record. I achieved this by using `if` statements in the `View`. This works as expected, but I would like to know if this is the best way to achieve this and if this is not the best way, I would like to know why so I can learn and improve my code.

This what I have in the `Controller`:

```
def show():
    x = db.mydatabase(request.args(0,cast=int))
    return dict(x=x)
```

This is what I have in the `View`:

```
{{if x.a_1:}}
<p style="color:white">some text {{=x.a_1}}</p>
<a class="link" href="{{=URL('download', args=x.c_1)}}"><p>some text</p></a>
<p>some text {{=x.b_1}}</p><br>
{{pass}}
```

Then I repeat the above `if` statement in the `View` 9 times, each time changing the number accordingly in `a_1`, `b_1` and `c_1`.

This works fine but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of repeating your code nine times, you can use a `for` loop:

```
{{for i in xrange(1, 10):}}
  {{if x['a_%s' % i]:}}
  <p style="color:white">some text {{=x['a_%s' % i]}}</p>
  <a class="link" href="{{=URL('download', args=x['c_%s' % i])}}"><p>some text</p></a>
  <p>some text {{=x['b_%s' % i]}}</p><br>
  {{pass}}
{{pass}}
```